# jquery-select2 showing first value selected by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, struts2

I am using below code for populating multi select :

```
    <s:select id = "deviceTypes" 
            name = "serviceVO.deviceTypes"
        multiple = "multiple" 
        required = "true"
  onBeforeTopics = "openLoader" 
onCompleteTopics = "closeLoader"
             key = "service.authoring.label.deviceTypes"
         tooltip = "%{getText('service .authoring.label.deviceTypes.info')}"
            list = "deviceTypesList" 
         listKey = "value" 
       listValue = "name"
        cssClass = "search-val form-control" />
```

and on document.ready i am calling :

```
 $("#deviceTypes").attr("multiple","true");
 $("#deviceTypes").select2();
```

With this it is showing by default first option value selected on page load which i don't want. I want user should select values and once user submit form then on modify page the selected values should be shown in select box and user can add or remove values.

Comment: @PracheerPanchoi I am confused with the code. Are you using `s:select` or `sj:select`. The `s:select` does not have `onBeforeTopics` or `onCompleteTopics`

Answer (score 2):

The `key` attribute is a shorthand to set with the same value three attributes: `name`, `value`, `label`.

As you should know, `value` (if present) preset the element's value, while `name` is used to send the parameter back to the action, and to preset the value in case `value` is missing.

Then using `key` in conjunction with one of the above attributes is misleading and wrong. 
Drop `key`, use `label` instead:

```
    <s:select id = "deviceTypes" 
            name = "serviceVO.deviceTypes"
        multiple = "multiple" 
        required = "true"
  onBeforeTopics = "openLoader" 
onCompleteTopics = "closeLoader"
           label = "service.authoring.label.deviceTypes"
         tooltip = "%{getText('service .authoring.label.deviceTypes.info')}"
            list = "deviceTypesList" 
         listKey = "value" 
       listValue = "name"
        cssClass = "search-val form-control" />
```

Note that `serviceVO.deviceTypes` must be an action attribute with a getter, of type List (or whatever) that is null the first time, and contains the selected values the next times is read.

Comment: deviceTypesList i am populating before page load . Is it possible without ajax if i have list already there then by default i can show empty select but when user click's on select box then list will be shown.

Comment: Not sure  what that means... too cryptic for me, sorry

Comment: @PracheerPancholi  I think you want your select box shows a default text for example `Please select a device type` or just a simple empty option as the first option. Am I correct ?!

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi i want empty option first time when page loads and then when user selects some options and after submitting form those selected values only should come among all other values. Also for this i don't want to have an ajax call as already i am populating list of values in action class.

Answer (score 1):

Still don't get exactly what you want.

But I think you can do this with some java script code. 
Create a `s:select` or `sj:select` which contains the options with all your data but make it invisible by `style="display: none"` . Make a second select box as normal `html select` with an empty option, this is what user see. So your main select box will be loaded the first time when page loads but user can not see it.

You can make it visible user make some actions, for example click a check box.

However submitting the form does not pass ALL select options to server, only the selected option will be send to server.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do with the below code on page load :

```
$("#deviceTypes").attr("multiple","true");
$("#deviceTypes").select2();
var selectedDevice=[];
var deviceList = '<s:property value="serviceVO.packagedService.deviceType" />';
$.each(deviceList, function(index,value) {
    selectedDevice.push(value); 
    });
 $("#deviceTypes").select2("val", selectedDevice);
```